# Variable only picking up one letter of passed string

Tags: c

I've been designing a test function as part of an assignment, and I am stuck on one part.  Basically, in order to get the loop to exit I need the state to be 9 and the s string to be "reset\0"   In testing I can reach state 9, which means inputChar() works as I need it to.  Another test indicates that inputString() is generating a valid string, but s is not getting the value correctly.  I am thinking it must be a pointer issue, btu I cannot figure out what after tinkering for a while.

```
int RandInt(int low, int high) {
  return low + rand() % (high - low + 1);
}

char inputChar()
{
    return RandInt(' ', '}');
}    

char *inputString()
    {
    int i;    
    char* iString[6];

    for (i = 0; i< 5; i++){
        iString[i] = RandInt('e', 't');
    }
    iString[5] = '\0';
    return iString;
}

void testme()
{
  int tcCount = 0;
  char *s;
  char c;
  int state = 0;
  while (1)
  {
    tcCount++;
    c = inputChar();
    s = inputString();
    printf("Iteration %d: c = %c, s = %s, state = %d\n", tcCount, c, s, state);

    if (c == '[' && state == 0) state = 1;
    if (c == '(' && state == 1) state = 2;
    if (c == '{' && state == 2) state = 3;
    if (c == ' '&& state == 3) state = 4;
    if (c == 'a' && state == 4) state = 5;
    if (c == 'x' && state == 5) state = 6;
    if (c == '}' && state == 6) state = 7;
    if (c == ')' && state == 7) state = 8;
    if (c == ']' && state == 8) state = 9;
    if (s[0] == 'r' && s[1] == 'e'
       && s[2] == 's' && s[3] == 'e'
       && s[4] == 't' && s[5] == '\0'
       && state == 9)
    {
      printf("error ");
      exit(200);
    }
  }
}
```

The input from running the above will run forever, because s is just a single character, and not "reset\0"

Comment: `char* iString[6];` --> `char *iString = malloc(6);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function inputString returns the address of its automatic variable that will cause undefined behavior as soon as you try to use it. You can modify your inputString function to receive a pointer as its argument and provide its output through this.

For example:

```
void inputString(char *iString)
{
    int i;    

    for (i = 0; i< 5; i++){
        iString[i] = RandInt('e', 't');
    }

    iString[5] = '\0';
}
```

and call the function with the following logic:

```
char iString[6];

inputString(iString);
```

Comment: Not to mention that probability of getting "reset" in 100 000 attempts is 12 % (77 % in 1 000 000 attempts and 99 % in 10 000 000)

Comment: the speed of this code makes 10 million attempts not a problem.  The goal is for it to be populated randomly (or else I'd just set it to reset)

Answer (score 0):

A problem in your code can be found here:

> ```
> char *inputString()
>     {
>     int i;    
>     char* iString[6];
>
>     for (i = 0; i< 5; i++){
>         iString[i] = RandInt('e', 't');
>     }
>     iString[5] = '\0';
>     return iString;
> }
> ```

You returned a pointer to a local array variable, `iString`. It's important that you have clear in your mind the **"lifetime"** of variables. `iString` exists *inside* the `inputString()` function.
When the function exits with the final `return` statement, that variable is destroyed.
So, you returned a pointer to a string that is *no more valid*.

There are several options that you have:

1. You can request the caller of the function to provide a destination string buffer as function parameter, and fill that buffer inside the function.
2. You can use a `static` local variable (whose lifetime extends the function scope), but I don't like it very much.
3. You can allocate memory using `malloc()` inside the function, and return a pointer to the allocated memory. The caller of the function must free that memory using `free()`.

Note also that if you want a string in C, you can do

```
char iString[6]; /* C string with max. 5 chars + NUL terminator */
```

not:

```
char* iString[6]; /* array of pointers to char's/strings */
```